# What's the difference between last_state and state in kubernetes V1ContainerStatus?

Tags: kubernetes

See: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ContainerStatus.md

I can't find documentation describing the difference between these two fields.

Comment: Found a page which helps a bit but doesn't fully explain the difference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#PodStatus

Answer (score 0):

It's for container's last state before it retried. Pod retries so the container restarts. Credit goes to Yuan Tang for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0):

The top level guides do not go into this low level detail.

You need to look at the  [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/) of which [v1.28](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.28/) appears to be latest

> LastTerminationState holds the last termination state of the container
> to help debug container crashes and restarts. This field is not
> populated if the container is still running and RestartCount is 0.

vs

> State holds details about the container's current condition.

Answer (score -2):

If the webserver stores data in a backend manner and uses it to identify the user as an always-connected client, the service is stateful. while in stateless the server does  store data but in a database to verify user/client

Comment: Hi! I was asking about the difference between last_state and state, not stateful and stateless.